# Почему возможно передача Double, наследника Number, в коллекцию с параметром типа <in Number>?

Tags: kotlin

Почему возможно передача Double, наследника Number, в коллекцию с параметром типа `<in Number>`?

`var list:MutableList<in Number> = mutableListOf() list.add(3.0)`

Если я правильно понял возможно передать Number и его супертип (т.е. от Number до Any), но Double является наследником?

Comment: [class Double : Number, Comparable<Double>](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не совсем верно понимаете значение `in/out` модификатора.
Он в вашем случае определяет тип списка, который вы можете присвоить переменной `list`.
Сам же метод `add()` принимает любой `Number`.

```
var list: MutableList<in Number> = mutableListOf()

list.add(3.0) // Success
list = mutableListOf<Double>() // Error
val list2: MutableList<in Double> = list // Success

println(list[0] is Double) // true
```

Вот в `list2` теперь, `Number` не добавить, только `Double`.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что метод add срабатывает потому, что на него не накладывается ограничение <in Number>, а только просто Number. И он срабатывает, т.к. срабатывает подстановка Барбары Лисков. А ограничение <in Number> накладывается только на переменную List, которой мы можем присвоить MutableList с параметром типа от Number до Any?

Comment: Да, я это тоже так понимаю.